# How can I draw the following commutative diagram?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the diagram I want to draw:

> [image]

Could anyone show me how can I draw it please?

Comment: I recommend `tikz-cd`

Comment: Can you provide the community with (1) A more descriptive title rather than "How can I draw this?" and (2) Some indication of what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend `tikz-cd`. The syntax is simple and the output high quality.

The only trick here is the `'` after the label to place it on the opposite side of the arrow (the default is on the left going from the source to the target).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[r] &
H \arrow[r,"\alpha"] \arrow[d,"\mathrm{id}"'] &
G \arrow[r,"\beta"] \arrow[d,"\theta"'] &
K \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"\mathrm{id}"'] &
1
\\
1 \arrow[r] &
H \arrow[r] &
H\times K \arrow[r] &
K \arrow[r] &
1
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The picture was produced with `xy`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  1 \ar[r] &
  H \ar[r]^{\alpha} \ar[d]_{\mathrm{id}} &
  G \ar[r]^{\beta} \ar[d]_{\theta} &
  K \ar[r] \ar[d]_{\mathrm{id}} &
  1
  \\
  1 \ar[r] &
  H \ar[r] &
  H\times K \ar[r] &
  K \ar[r] &
  1
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I recommend

```
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
```

which produces much better arrows

[image]